# Getting Cannot execute "delete" on "Article" in CASL JS

Tags: casl, dynamic-permissions

I'm learning CASL JS and trying to delete an article with a condition but getting this error  `Cannot execute "delete" on "Article"`. Here is the [CodeSandBox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/casl-demo-roles-with-static-permissions-forked-pt9rzs?file=/src/index.ts).

Here is the sample code:

```
const { createMongoAbility, ForbiddenError } = require("@casl/ability");

const rules = [
  {
    action: "read",
    subject: "Article"
  },
  {
    inverted: true,
    action: "delete",
    subject: "Article",
    conditions: { published: true },
    reason: "You are not allowed to delete this article"
  }
];

const ability = createMongoAbility(rules);

// this can be pulled from a database
class Article {
  constructor(attrs) {
    Object.assign(this, attrs);
  }
}

const anotherArticle = new Article({
  authorId: 2,
  published: false,
  content: "Lorem Ipsum"
});

try {
  // checking ability before taking some action
  ForbiddenError.from(ability).throwUnlessCan("delete", anotherArticle);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error.message); // throwing `Cannot execute "delete" on "Article"`
}
```

Please help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The creator of CASL JS has answered this:

> you declared that it's not possible to delete published articles but you have never said that it's possible to delete articles at all. That's why you get the error

So this means that I already declared inverted permission and it's not possible to delete articles.

[image]